# I'm trying to slice my c++ array from the second to the last index

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm trying to emulate the `echo` command in C++.
I'm trying to slice the the program name off of the entry values and push the 
rest to the command line. BUT I'm getting weird errors.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  if(argv[1] == "echo"){
    cout << args[2:];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But I get the error(s):

```cpp
    cmd.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
    cmd.cpp:6:13: error: 'args' was not declared in this scope
         cout << args[:];
                 ^~~~
    cmd.cpp:6:13: note: suggested alternative: 'argc'
         cout << args[:];
                 ^~~~
                 argc
    cmd.cpp:6:18: error: expected primary-expression before ':' token
         cout << args[:];
                      ^
    cmd.cpp:6:18: error: expected ']' before ':' token
         cout << args[:];
                      ^
                      ]
```

I am trying to take {1234545, "hello", ", world!"} and turn It into "hello, world!" Basically what I want to do is get rid of array[0] and joining the rest of the list together.

**EDIT:** Thanks @chipster for giving a great answer!

Comment: The error is pretty clear "error: 'args' was not declared in this scope"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor issue (I mean, I guess it's a big one, as it's the one causing the compiler error, but once you fix it, you're going to get rammed with another error really quick, so...): `args` does not exist. You actually want `argv` instead.

---

The syntax `arr[i:j]` it Python syntax, not C++.

To do the equivalent in C++, do this instead:

```
for(int i=2;i<argc;i++) {
    std::cout << argv[i] << "\n"; // "\n" is just to make things look nicer.
        // "\n" could be any separator
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got if fixed!

Comment: Awesome. If this answer solved your problem, you can upvote this answer or accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer..